# Resources for Learning Pure AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Similar question: [Best Resources for Learning AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92602/best-resources-for-learning-as3)

I am interested in learning AS3 and have downloaded FlashDevelop and played around with it a bit, learning some of the fundamentals. However, when I attempt to start on any relatively simple project (eg. a multipage document) I get completely lost and have no idea how I should build my project. Are there any resources, tutorials, 'cookbooks' etc. that teach actionscript 3 through example projects. I keep finding books that explain the fundamentals of the actionscript syntax or tutorials that explain how to use actionscript to complete a task in the Flash IDE but this is not what I am after.

Where can I learn how to create projects in pure AS3 without the aid of the Flash IDE or Flex? I don't mind if I have to create assets in the Flash IDE that I then compile to .swf or .swc for use in my actionscript code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Resources for Learning AS3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92602/best-resources-for-learning-as3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice is: learn Flex focusing strongly on MXML, or learn Haxe.

AS3 is verbous, unexpressive and unproductive compared to those two.

**edit:** you can check out the [AS3 cookbook](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/as3_cookbook_excerpts.html). nonetheless, after rereading your post, I've come to understand, that your problem is not learning AS3, but you're rather having design problems. Am I correct?

**edit2:** *"Is it uncommon for people to work in pure AS3?"*

I wouldn't say, it's uncommon. I'd say it's even common, i.e. a common mistake. Why? It's inefficient. I think, I can tell, because I did that a lot.

the main role of pure AS3 is to create libraries and frameworks. To create actual apps, it is really the hardest way one can choose. In all handmade apps, GUI turns out to be the most time consuming part. Laying out GUI using code is a nightmare.

Now MXML is really great for normal GUIs (a graphical editor is even better of course). And the Flash IDE is great for creating funky animated things. The best thing you can do with AS3 is take ASWing and their GUI-editor. As nice as ASWing is, its ugly and a pain in the arse to skin. But, you can.

The advantage of Haxe is, that its a more powerful language than AS3. You effectively write less code, and its signifficantly more typesafe, so you run into less errors and spend less time debugging. Also, another advantage is, that you can use the same language for creating a serverside backend for the app and pass objects transparently to it, using Haxe remoting, which cuts the transport layer down to nothing. All validation and business logic can run both on client or server. Plus it's open source and it evolves very fast. AS3 was a great thing when it came, but it has stalled eversince, which is nearly 4 years now.

So while there's nothing wrong using pure AS3 per se, you always have to compare it to the alternatives. Pure AS3 is inefficient and for geeks. Flex is highly efficient. Haxe is more efficient than AS3, and is for the really cool geeks.

Comment: Thanks. Is it uncommon for people to work in pure AS3? I had heard of haXe but never considered it; I'll take a look at it now. You are correct, I have no trouble learning AS3, but am having a design problems.

Comment: I am with back2dos on supporting haXe. Recently used it to write a library. With the addition of generics and inlining it made my life easier. All that is missing is a debugger. Also for design pattern books check out "Advanced ActionScript 3 with Design Patterns by Joey Lott and Danny Paterson". Just be careful that you don't try and use a design pattern for every programming problem.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is comprehensive and has really helped me understand the roles of AS3, Flex/MXML and the Flash IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out Essential ActionScript 3.0 by Colin Moock that was in the other question? [here is a preview on google books](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=gUHX2fcLKxYC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_navlinks_s#v=onepage&q=&f=false)

Comment: To be honest, I was a bit disappointed when I read it. Maybe my expectations where just to hight, because everyone treated it like a bible. :D

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I've already looked at it. I am looking for something that goes through the process of building things with AS3 and explaining how to go about doing so rather than a book about syntax and general information.

Comment: @back2dos I found it a good book when first starting out but once you advance its usefulness decreases :)