# Where do i find some AS3 resources for a Newbie to AS3, not to programming

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm a fairly experienced Web Developer. I know the LAMP stack, I can work with Javascript from a procedural level. What I'm looking for is a good resource for someone without previous Action Script experience to get his head in the game. These days for JS I usually just use jQuery and it solves most all of my UI needs. However, as time goes on, I see that I need to enhance my skill set by learning to at-least do the most rudimentary things with flash via AS3. I've worked with C, C++, Java, C# within educational settings. I know what objects are, strict typing, even generic classes, stacks, queues etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not long ago, I've answered [a question similar to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333570/resources-for-learning-pure-as3).
Maybe for you Haxe is actually the right choice.

other than that, check out actionscript.org

Answer (score 0):

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/ is not a bad starting point

If you want books then the following are good:

[http://www.amazon.com/Essential-ActionScript-3-0-Colin-Moock/dp/0596526946](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526946)

[http://www.amazon.com/ActionScript-3-0-Cookbook-Application-Developers/dp/0596526954](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526954)

There is also ActionScript Design Patterns book, which is supposed to be nice.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much time you have and how much you want to learn. 
You could start with the official developer guide from http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/devguide_flex3.pdf

Comment: Yes, but this is flex, not as3